# Email change From: address

Tags: c#, asp.net, contact-form

I'm doing a property listing site and is now preparing a contact form for each property.

As my client is also using a ticketing system which parse emails from a dedicated mailbox, it requires me to configure the contact form to email to the dedicated mailbox for their system to pick it up. I'm using ASP C#.

I need help on changing the "From" address in the contact form to the sender's email address in the form, codes are as shown below:

This is my aspx.cs

```
protected void SendMail()
{
    var fromAddress = "email@domain.com";
    var toAddress = "dedicatedmailbox@domain.com";
    const string fromPassword = "password";
    string subject = PropertyNameOnContact.Text.ToString();
    string body = "Subject: Online Enquiry for " + PropertyNameOnContact.Text + "\n";
    body += "Email: " + txtemail.Text + "\n";
    body += "From: " + txtname.Text + "\n";
    body += "Preferred contact Method: \n" + PreferredContact.Text + "\n";

    var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
    {
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
        smtp.Timeout = 20000;
    }

    smtp.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, body);
}
```

Comment: What is the question? What problems are you having?

Comment: How about setting `fromAddress` to `txtemail.Text`?

Comment: If you want `txtEmail` field to contain value from `fromAddress`, you need to assign it like `txtemail.Text = fromAddress`. And please, ask understandable questions, it's impossible to comprehend what do you want.

Comment: Let me get this straight, you're looking to send an email from a "Contact Us"-kind of a form ? You can either ask the user to register where you're going to collect his email address and use it each time he fills this form. Or you can possibly place a textbox on the form that is required and validate the value provided by the user (possibly by a regex) ? I hope I understood the question correctly.

Answer (score 2):

For a contact form like this, the address filled in by the user should never be the address used as from address. It should be the reply-to address. This is done so that the receiving mail server can make correct validations.

I suggest you create a `MailMessage` object, on which you can set all these parameters that the shorthand `SmtpClient.Send` doesn't have. On that you can add your addresses that should be replied to in `MailMessage.ReplyToList`, and the from adress as `MailMessage.From`.

The `SmtpClient.Send` method also accepts a `MailMessage` object, so it should be fairly easy.

Here's the MailMessage object on MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As know there are two ways. which will not Affect any of the existing Process,
Try this

- get the From Email-ID (fromAddress) from DataBase
- Configure the From Email_ID (fromAddress) in Web Config File which u can Access it for the Entire application.

u can change them whenever u want. without changing the C# source code.